# Virtual environment not recognized in WSGIPythonPath

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up my Django project in production by using a virtual environment, using the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv

So, in my configuration I have:

```
WSGIPythonPath /srv/zboss/zboss:/srv/zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

I restart Apache and I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /prot/

InvalidTemplateLibrary at /
Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'core.templatetags.wiki_formatter': No module named parse

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://babylon/prot/
Django Version: 1.10.1
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path: ['/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/srv/zboss/zboss']
```

However the error is something because that library is not used anymore in Python3. I see the python path and no trace of my virtual environment directory.

Comment: Did you forget to activate your virtualenv?

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues I think it's not necesary since you're pointing out the location of that directory

Comment: Sorry. I misread the question. Try removing `/srv/zboss/zboss:` from the path and seeing if it works (or at least if the error shows the correct path)

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.7. You cannot point it at a virtual environment for Python 3.4. You must uninstall mod_wsgi and install a mod_wsgi version built for Python 3.4, the same version as your virtual environment.

Comment: How can I keep both of them? I have in the same server some other projects using Python2.7.

Comment: You can't use multiple Python versions within the same Apache instance. Consider looking at mod_wsgi-express and have it sitting behind your main Apache, where the main Apache acts as a proxy to it. If sound like an option, then jump on the mod_wsgi mailing list and ask about it there as that is better place to discuss it. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/finding-help.html