# Trying to run 2 Python applications with different Python versions with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, moinmoin

I have in my Apache 2 applications: Django app and MoinMoin app. The first one is running now with Python3.4 and the second one (MoinMoin) with Python2.7

When running dpkg:

```
ruben@babylon:/var/log/apache2$ dpkg -l | grep wsgi
rc  libapache2-mod-wsgi                   3.4-4ubuntu2.1.14.04.2                amd64        Python WSGI adapter module for Apache
ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3               3.4-4ubuntu2.1.14.04.2                amd64        Python 3 WSGI adapter module for Apache
```

but Apache can't run the 2 modules at the same time. Django (Python3) is working but MoinMoin (Python2.7) not. How can I fix that?

Comment: You would be needing 2  separate gunicorn process. One for Python 3 and another for 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you were told already in:

- [Virtual environment not recognized in WSGIPythonPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043543/virtual-environment-not-recognized-in-wsgipythonpath)

you cannot do that within a single Apache instance.

The simple answer as was described is to run a separate WSGI server such as `mod_wsgi-express`, or you can use `gunicorn` our something else as well, and set it up behind the main Apache instance it with Apache proxying to it.

There are a lot of details around doing this and as also suggested, you are better off asking on the mod_wsgi mailing list if you want to do this with mod_wsgi.

If don't wish to use the mod_wsgi mailing list, then you can find some information in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html

It talks about proxying to backend WSGI application running in Docker, but all the same principles apply as to setting up the proxy fronted and the issues that arise.